# Swiper makes div taller than given and doesn't shrink when height is given

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, swiper.js

I made a limit on the swiper height of 50%, the swiper block really became smaller, but the height of the div block itself remained the same. How can I solve the div issue? The problem is visible on the screenshot, if I make the height of .mySwiper2 80%, then everything will be ok.
[image]

[image]

CSS style

```
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.mySwiper2 {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper {
    height: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

html swiper block

```
<div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {% for slide in self.slides %}
            <div class="swiper-slide popup-gallery ">
                {% for type, slide_ in slide.items %}
                    {% if type == 'image' %}
                        {% if slide_ %}
                            {% image slide.image original as tmp_photo %}
                            <a href="{{ tmp_photo.url }}" class="popup-gallery"><img src="{{ tmp_photo.url }}"></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if slide_ %}
                            <a class="video" id="youtube-{{ slide_ }}"
                               href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ slide_ }}">
                                <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{ slide_ }}/hq720.jpg">
                                <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {% for slide in self.slides %}
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                {% for type, slide_ in slide.items %}
                    {% if type == 'image' %}
                        {% if slide_ %}
                            {% image slide.image original as tmp_photo %}
                            <img src="{{ tmp_photo.url }}">
                        {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if slide_ %}
                            <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{ slide_ }}/hq720.jpg">
                            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.mySwiper2 {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XayyES2vO8Q/hq720.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make an example on codepen or sth with HTML and CSS? Your code consist of other unrelated things that make it harder to debug

Comment: @TreeNguyen Please don't use an external site to put your code into, use the StackOverflow snippet system. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. (The reason for this is that external sites can disappear and then the question and any answers become less relevant for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any wrong in the image or the code, everything is working fine.

You set the `mySwiper2` height to `50%` and it's already 50% and you set the `mySwiper` height to 20% and it's already 20%.

I don't see anything strange here, and I really didn't get the point from the question.

Can you clarify the question some more so I can help you.

Comment: look at the picture of the problem. The height of the swiper blocks itself is normal, but the size of the div in which it is located is as if the height of the sweeper block is 80%.
I highlighted the div containing the swiper in black and this div should be the same height as the swiper.

Comment: I think you can solve the forced height and width that swiper cause with just the `min-height` `max-height` `min-width` and `max-width` because somethings in swiper are styled in the swiper css file.
And again, I didn't really figure out the problem, I don't see where exactly the wrong so I can help more.
But I think that using the min, max width and height can solve this type of problems because this type of problem faced me many times.